# How to convert NVARCHAR comma-delimited list to INT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

Is there a way to do the following in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @list nvarchar(MAX) = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ( @list );

-- Column ID is type bigint
```

Error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) or so many similar questions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to convert it to an int.  Instead, use `like` for the comparison:

```
select *
from table
where ', '+@list+', ' like ', '+cast(id as varchar(255)) + ', ';
```

This has the downside that the query will not use indexes.  If that is important, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @list nvarchar(10) = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6';
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ('+ @list +')';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 5):

use `Dynamic SQL`.

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @list nvarchar(10) = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6';

SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (' + @list + ')'
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```